# Running a multi-module Maven web app with Jetty, HTTP ERROR: 503 SERVICE_UNAVAILABLE

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, jetty

I have a multi-module Maven web app, and I want to run it in Eclipse with Jetty. I read several tutorials ([here is](http://eureka.ykyuen.info/2010/03/08/maven-run-webapp-by-maven-jetty-plugin/) one I tried to follow).

I thought that everything that is need to be done is adding plugins and dependencies in the `pom.xml` of my Spring web module of the project and then with a help of `mvn jetty:run` (again, in the web Spring Maven module) run the app and be able to see the results in the browser. So, the first question is: do I have to do something else (e.g. in the `web.xml` file)?

**EDIT**:
I also had to add `<pluginGroup>org.mortbay.jetty</pluginGroup>` in Maven's settings.xml to start server without errors.

And I get `HTTP ERROR: 503 SERVICE_UNAVAILABLE`. What are the probable reasons? Do I need some more dependencies or to add something else? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to what was written when Jetty tried to start, I had to add MySql dependency. With it `HTTP ERROR: 503 SERVICE_UNAVAILABLE` disappeared.

Here is the part of the `pom.xml` of the Spring web module of my project I added to use Jetty (Just in case someone needs it. Maybe, I could delete something from this `pom.xml`'s part, I haven't check that yet.):

```
  <build>

      <plugins>
        <plugin>
          <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
          <artifactId>maven-site-plugin</artifactId>
          <!-- Lock down plugin version for build reproducibility -->
          <version>3.0</version>
        </plugin>  

        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.mortbay.jetty</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-jetty-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>6.1.14</version>
            <configuration>
                <connectors>
                    <connector implementation="org.mortbay.jetty.nio.SelectChannelConnector">
                        <port>9090</port>
                        <maxIdleTime>60000</maxIdleTime>
                    </connector>
                </connectors>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>

        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.6</source>
                <target>1.6</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
     </plugins>

  </build>

  <properties>
      <org.springframework.version>3.1.0.RELEASE</org.springframework.version>
      <jetty.version>6.1.14</jetty.version>
  </properties>

  <dependencies>
    <!-- In my case Jetty needs this one to run -->   
    <dependency>
      <groupId>mysql</groupId>
      <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
      <version>5.1.6</version>
    </dependency>        
    <!-- Jetty dependencies -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.mortbay.jetty</groupId>
        <artifactId>jetty</artifactId>
        <version>${jetty.version}</version>
        <type>jar</type>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.mortbay.jetty</groupId>
        <artifactId>jetty-util</artifactId>
        <version>${jetty.version}</version>
        <type>jar</type>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.mortbay.jetty</groupId>
        <artifactId>jetty-plus</artifactId>
        <version>${jetty.version}</version>
        <type>jar</type>
    </dependency>
    <!--The 2 following are the jsp support for jetty -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.mortbay.jetty</groupId>
        <artifactId>jsp-2.1</artifactId>
        <version>${jetty.version}</version>
        <type>jar</type>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.mortbay.jetty</groupId>
        <artifactId>jsp-api-2.1</artifactId>
        <version>${jetty.version}</version>
        <type>jar</type>
    </dependency>
```

Answer (score 1):

First you need to add the plugin also to the usual build part and not only to the pluginManagement block.

```
  <project ...>

    <build>
       <plugins>
          <plugin>
            <groupId>org.mortbay.jetty</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-jetty-plugin</artifactId>
          </plugin>
          ...
       </plugins>
..
    </build>
  </project>
```

Furthermore i recommend you to update the [maven-site-plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-site-plugin/), cause you are using a extremely old one.

Comment: I see, thanks, I'll update it. I edited the question, your answer helped, but Jetty still isn't working properly. After adding <pluginGroup>org.mortbay.jetty</pluginGroup> in Maven's settings.xml server started without errors. Oh, and thanks a lot for your daily help with my Maven questions! :)